# WP hello-elementor theme: Post comment button has a weird border in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I created a WordPress site with the hello-elementor theme:
https://taligrade-profits.000webhostapp.com/hallo-welt/

When I click the "Post Comment" button the button displays a black border (only in Google Chrome). I want to get rid of this effect.

I also added a little bit of CSS (because I want to design that button like this):

```
.submit {
    background-color: #8766ff;
    border: none !important;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.submit:hover {
    background-color: #8766ff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I cannot get rid of this "focus" event, it's neither a border nor a margin. And it only appears in Chrome.

How can I get rid of this focus border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border you're seeing is an [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

> Borders and outlines are very similar. However, outlines differ from borders in the following ways:
>
> - Outlines never take up space, as they are drawn outside of an element's content.
> - According to the spec, outlines don't have to be rectangular, although they usually are.

You can remove it like so:

```css
.submit:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @CodeBrot Glad it worked, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted :)